Momentary solo circuit
I'm looking for an idea/schematic of how to make a "soloing" circuit with momentary push buttons. What I'm looking for is something that will "solo" that one path of the circuit wile "muting" all of the other paths while pressing the button. I'm using audio terminology as this is something that is used on recording consoles but I wasn't able to find any information about that online.
To illustrate my idea I'm posting a picture with a simple LED circuit here. Normally all of the LEDs would light up at the same time but how to make it so only one lights up when a button is pushed and how to make it so every path has its own "solo" button?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Edit: Wow, thanks for all the replies! The community here amazing! For now I will stick with DPDT switches method as it is the simplest for me to grasp (I'm new to electronics). Can't wait to breadboard it in!

Are the paths in your audio circuit connected together somehow like summing or etc? If yes, how exactly?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you're describing radio button behavior

If the circuit you posted is a metaphor, what are the signals you actually want to control - audio, sensors, DC to LEDs, other - ?

@jsotola, no, a radio group would have only one on or none on (if you unlatch them all somehow - mechanical buttons required a delicate touch). This requires all on or one on and no latch.

it's one thing to talk about LEDs, entirely another to talk about audio. In a mixing desk, you have anything from 4 to 48 sources, you can SOLO any combination of them, and the main MIX is disconnected, and (a mix of) all the channels which are in SOLO are heard in isolation. There HAS to be a SOLO mix bus to achieve this. Your example of LEDs is a different problem. Do you want to SOLO LEDs or audio?

I'm building a simple synth with 6 separate oscillators and all of the signals are going to be summed at the last stage via 100kOhm resistors to one mono out. I know consoles are way more advances (I'm an audio engineer myself) but for this project DPDT switches will be adequate.

Using double pole switches like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
or like this is you want to allow duets etc:

simulate this circuit

It is always done with a separate bus. The solutions above might work, but try expanding that to a desk with 24 or 48 channels.
The system used is as follows:

on the bus cable (typically one or more large ribbon cables connecting all modules) there are two wires allocated. One is a logic signal that says one or more modules is activating SOLO. The other is a virtual earth summing bus for SOLO audio.

On the master module, there is a summing amp for SOLO, and the logic signal has the effect of switching the monitor (NOT mix) output to the SOLO bus.


I will try to draw it, not sure how well it will work with the software used here - a block diagram is really what is wanted.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In practice, everything is stereo at the master end, we would use FET switches not a relay, there will also be LEDs (both on the master and each source) the sum amp would have many refinements, and so on, but this is how it is always done on an analogue desk.
The reason it is done this way is that you only need two bus wires, no matter how many sources - and there can be 50 to 100 of them, even more on a large desk, and cores on that bus connector are used jealously. Other approaches simply do not scale.
There is another reason why schemes like "daisy chaining" of switches (as suggested by other answers here) would not be acceptable in a professional, modular mixer : it has to be possible to remove modules for service, and keep the rest of the desk functional. Also, daisy chain arrangements are not fault tolerant - if one device goes open circuit, the whole system fails. (And with a large desk having very many mechanical switches, this is a fairly common issue as contacts oxidise and so on.) Bus designs are far better at handling failure of one device on the bus - the only system level issue is if the bus itself gets shorted or goes open, which is rare.

I'll adapt your question to have three "channels", not four, but you can extend the ideas presented here for any number of them. These are just a couple of approaches, out of probably dozens that would also work.
You can treat this as a digital "logic problem", and use logic gates to implement it. Here's a truth table describing the state of switches A, B and C, where "1" represents a switch pressed, and the corresponding desired outputs X, Y and Z, where "1" represents a lit LED:
$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline A & B & C & X & Y & Z \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline 
\end{array}
$$
Not all combinations of A, B and C are shown, only those states where a single switch is pressed, or none of them. An English description of this behaviour might be: an LED is on if:

its own associated switch is pressed

OR

all three switches are released

The second condition can be detected with a NOR gate, and the OR operation can be implemented with, well, an OR gate. The switch logic levels "1" (high) or "0" (low) can be implemented by pairing each switch with a resistor. Here's the complete circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Appropriate ICs to use are:

4002, with dual 4-input NOR gates, one of which is used for G4
4071, with quad 2-input OR gates, used for G1, G2 and G3.

There are other combinations of gates you could employ to achieve the same result, but using this particular design, you could easily extend it to control actual current paths, for audio or LED current, using an analogue switch IC like this:

simulate this circuit
A suitable IC for this would be the 4016, which contains four digitally-controlled analogue switches.
If you want to control high-voltage or high-current devices, you can adapt the circuit with transistors, to operate relays:

simulate this circuit
At the risk of getting confusing, the same logical relationship between A, B and C, and X, Y and Z, can be achieved using transistors and diodes, not an IC in sight:

simulate this circuit
I'm not saying this is the best way, just that there are many ways, and which one you use will depend entirely on your own application.

The circuits below show various approaches that trade off the number and type of components. When selecting a circuit, you'll have to understand the tradeoffs and choose something that makes sense in your application.
1. SPST switches, ≈N2 diodes
The following circuit requires, for \$N\$ LEDs:

\$N\$ simple NO (normally open) single-pole pushbuttons,
\$N\cdot(N-1)\$ diodes - any Si, Schottky or Ge diode will do, 1N400x, 1N4148, etc.

The circuit works by shunting the current around the LEDs to ground, using regular signal or rectifier diodes to act as a switching matrix. The current draw from the power supply is roughly constant, independently of how many LEDs are ON at a given time.
When multiple SOLO buttons are pressed at the same time, all LEDs are OFF. Thus, ensembles disable all LEDs.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
2. SPDT switches, N or 2N diodes
The following circuit requires, for \$N\$ LEDs:

\$N\$ NO-NC (double-throw, form C) pushbuttons,
\$N\$ diodes - any Si, Schottky or Ge diode will do, 1N400x, 1N4148, etc.

This circuit doesn't waste power - when a single LED is active, only that LED consumes current. This circuit does not allow duets. The lowest-numbered solo has the highest priority. E.g. when SOLO2 and SOLO4 are both depressed, only SOLO2 is allowed since its priority is higher. Ensembles allow only the lowest-numbered soloist.

simulate this circuit
The LED intensity is very slightly higher when the solo mode is active, since there's one less diode drop in the LED supply. If that behavior is undesirable, add series diodes to solo circuits as below:

simulate this circuit
3. SPST and DPST switches, 2 transistors
Another approach uses SPST and SPDT switches, and a current source to drive the LEDs. The switches redirect the current around the non-solo LEDs. Ensembles are not allowed - all LEDs are off when any multiple SOLO switches are turned on. Ensembles disable all LEDs.

simulate this circuit
Since a current source is used, the LED brightness doesn't vary much when the power supply voltage varies - as long as there's enough forward voltage for the LEDs etc.
The current source could be an LM334 with a single resistor, instead of the transistor circuit.
4. SPST switches, N transistors, N-2 diodes
This is a variation on the previous circuit, using transistors instead of the 2nd pole of the switches.
With PNP transistors

simulate this circuit
With NPN transistors

simulate this circuit
The NPN transistors can be the same type as used in the current source, reducing the number of bill-of-material (BOM) lines.
60 years ago, transistors were expensive and less reliable than good quality switches. Today, switches are much less reliable than transistors - not because they are inherently bad, but because the transistors are so good nowadays. Of course the cent-level cost cutting in consumer goods is making switches look worse than they should be :(
It may seem weird to replace a part of a switch with a transistor, but it helps one afford better quality switches, since they are simpler (SPST, not SPDT etc) when transistors and/or diodes help out.
For the same money, you can get a bit more of a switch when the switch is simpler - when buying new switches in high quantities. Second-hand/new-old-stock switches are very much a hit-or-miss. The prices often have more to do with the willingness and urgency of the seller to get rid of them than quality. But old stock quality US made switches - say from C&K and Raytheon - can be a great deal, and are really a no-brainer. If you can get them - use them.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. A simple diode circuit.
This works on the principle that the voltage drop of D5 to D16, being only 0.7 V or so will, when a button is pressed, pull the LED voltage to well below its forward voltage - 2 V, say.

Here's a way, using a diode matrix, momentary push button switches S1, S2, S3 and magnetic latch relays K1, K2, K3.

'NO' contacts of the relays K1, K2 & K3 are to be used to switch the signals.
Relays with gold plated contacts are a must if low level signals are to be switched.
Freewheeling diodes for the relay coils and LED indicators are not shown.

Since 6 answers isn't nearly enough, here's another.
If the specification can be tweaked slightly (arguably for the better!) then only one transistor and two resistors are needed, regardless of how many channels there are, and only requires the simplest switch type, SPST.
The trick is to use bi-color LEDs: they all glow one color (e.g. GREEN) until a button is pressed which turns them all off and turns on the other color (e.g. RED) for the selected (solo) channel.
My original schematic required 4-pin LEDs which are really only available in surface mount.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This revised schematic uses the much more available 3-pin common cathode parts.
In the highly unlikely event the B diode has a significantly higher turn on voltage than A, adding D5 will ensure the A diodes aren't still faintly on when a button is pressed.
Tweak R1 to get desired brightness for B LEDs.
Tweak R2 for desired A brightness, lower value for more LEDs.

simulate this circuit
